# SVG Pulse Animation Not Recognizing Class

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I can't seem to animate a heart I created in illustrator to scale with a pulse animation. Can not for the life of me figure out what is wrong. Also maybe am I am just missing something simple here, because I have stared at this so long. Thank you for your help.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d9d7be;
  text-align: center;
}

.heart{
  animation: pulse linear 1s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: pulse linear 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%{transform: scale (1);}
  30%{transform: scale (1);}
  40%{transform: scale (1.08);}
  50%{transform: scale (1);}
  60%{transform: scale (1);}
  70%{transform: scale (1.05);}
  80%{transform: scale (1);}
  100%{transform: scale (1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0%{-webkit-transform: scale (1);}
  30%{-webkit-transform: scale (1);}
  40%{-webkit-transform: scale (1.08);}
  50%{-webkit-transform: scale (1);}
  60%{-webkit-transform: scale (1);}
  70%{-webkit-transform: scale (1.05);}
  80%{-webkit-transform: scale (1);}
  100%{-webkit-transform: scale (1);}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="597px" height="593px" viewBox="0 0 597 593" enable-background="new 0 0 597 593" xml:space="preserve">
    <g class="heart">
   <path fill="#FF7175" d="M258.08,255.405c-0.898-7.654,0.082-16.847,6.735-20.737c8.806-5.149,19.895,3.531,23.278,13.154
  c3.316-9.961,12.405-18.064,22.851-19.111c10.447-1.047,21.467,5.766,24.211,15.9c2.152,7.952-0.72,16.59-5.632,23.206
  c-4.911,6.614-11.671,11.579-18.323,16.439c-7.933,5.795-15.865,11.59-23.795,17.384
  C281.945,295.363,259.763,269.744,258.08,255.405"/>
   <path fill="#DADCDD" d="M320.746,276.922c3.236-2.739,6.25-5.704,8.776-9.105c0.044-0.06,0.089-0.119,0.132-0.179
  c-0.043,0.06-0.088,0.119-0.132,0.179C326.996,271.218,323.982,274.183,320.746,276.922 M257.797,250.701
  c0.001-6.215,1.593-12.537,6.559-15.751C259.39,238.164,257.798,244.486,257.797,250.701 M264.814,234.668
  c0.02-0.012,0.039-0.023,0.059-0.034C264.854,234.645,264.834,234.656,264.814,234.668 M264.881,234.629
  c1.255-0.723,2.554-1.166,3.872-1.367C267.436,233.464,266.135,233.907,264.881,234.629"/>
   <path fill="#D7616B" d="M287.404,301.64c-0.006-0.006-0.011-0.012-0.016-0.019c-5.304-6.098-26.173-30.213-29.074-44.751
  c-0.1-0.5-0.178-0.989-0.234-1.465l0,0c-0.179-1.525-0.283-3.111-0.283-4.704c0.001-6.215,1.593-12.537,6.559-15.751
  c0.15-0.097,0.303-0.191,0.459-0.282l0,0c0.02-0.012,0.039-0.023,0.059-0.034c0.002-0.002,0.005-0.003,0.007-0.005
  c1.254-0.722,2.555-1.165,3.872-1.367c0.565-0.086,1.134-0.128,1.703-0.128c5.753,0,11.591,4.258,15.168,9.742
  c-1.132,9.498-7.344,20.871-3.758,28.043c0.76,1.139,1.682,1.624,2.729,1.624c5.031-0.002,12.926-11.2,19.312-14.849
  c3.27-1.961,6.828-2.855,10.305-2.855c7.234,0,14.109,3.873,17.255,10.062c-0.565,0.942-1.168,1.858-1.812,2.737
  c-0.043,0.06-0.088,0.119-0.132,0.179c-2.526,3.401-5.54,6.366-8.776,9.105c-3.059,2.587-6.315,4.973-9.547,7.334
  C303.267,290.051,295.334,295.845,287.404,301.64L287.404,301.64"/>
    </g>
  </svg>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="1s" type="scale" from="1" to="2" repeatCount="indefinite" />`

and

`<animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="20s" type="transalte" from="0 0" to="-250 -250" repeatCount="indefinite" />`

should help you get you on your way.

You need to create another layer `g` which you translate, and then you can scale the inner `g`. So your heart remains centered.

If you want to create a chained animation you can ditch `from` and `to` and replace it with `values="x;y;z"` where a semicolon denotes another keyframe.

```
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="597px" height="593px" viewBox="0 0 597 593" enable-background="new 0 0 597 593" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="1s" type="translate" values="0 0; -250 -250; 0 0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            <g>
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="1s" type="scale" values="1; 2; 1" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <path fill="#FF7175" d="M258.08,255.405c-0.898-7.654,0.082-16.847,6.735-20.737c8.806-5.149,19.895,3.531,23.278,13.154
        c3.316-9.961,12.405-18.064,22.851-19.111c10.447-1.047,21.467,5.766,24.211,15.9c2.152,7.952-0.72,16.59-5.632,23.206
        c-4.911,6.614-11.671,11.579-18.323,16.439c-7.933,5.795-15.865,11.59-23.795,17.384
        C281.945,295.363,259.763,269.744,258.08,255.405" />
                <path fill="#DADCDD" d="M320.746,276.922c3.236-2.739,6.25-5.704,8.776-9.105c0.044-0.06,0.089-0.119,0.132-0.179
        c-0.043,0.06-0.088,0.119-0.132,0.179C326.996,271.218,323.982,274.183,320.746,276.922 M257.797,250.701
        c0.001-6.215,1.593-12.537,6.559-15.751C259.39,238.164,257.798,244.486,257.797,250.701 M264.814,234.668
        c0.02-0.012,0.039-0.023,0.059-0.034C264.854,234.645,264.834,234.656,264.814,234.668 M264.881,234.629
        c1.255-0.723,2.554-1.166,3.872-1.367C267.436,233.464,266.135,233.907,264.881,234.629" />
                <path fill="#D7616B" d="M287.404,301.64c-0.006-0.006-0.011-0.012-0.016-0.019c-5.304-6.098-26.173-30.213-29.074-44.751
        c-0.1-0.5-0.178-0.989-0.234-1.465l0,0c-0.179-1.525-0.283-3.111-0.283-4.704c0.001-6.215,1.593-12.537,6.559-15.751
        c0.15-0.097,0.303-0.191,0.459-0.282l0,0c0.02-0.012,0.039-0.023,0.059-0.034c0.002-0.002,0.005-0.003,0.007-0.005
        c1.254-0.722,2.555-1.165,3.872-1.367c0.565-0.086,1.134-0.128,1.703-0.128c5.753,0,11.591,4.258,15.168,9.742
        c-1.132,9.498-7.344,20.871-3.758,28.043c0.76,1.139,1.682,1.624,2.729,1.624c5.031-0.002,12.926-11.2,19.312-14.849
        c3.27-1.961,6.828-2.855,10.305-2.855c7.234,0,14.109,3.873,17.255,10.062c-0.565,0.942-1.168,1.858-1.812,2.737
        c-0.043,0.06-0.088,0.119-0.132,0.179c-2.526,3.401-5.54,6.366-8.776,9.105c-3.059,2.587-6.315,4.973-9.547,7.334
        C303.267,290.051,295.334,295.845,287.404,301.64L287.404,301.64" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems easier to remove the invalid spaces than totally rewrite it. But this works too I guess.

Comment: Nit: animateTransform doesn't redefine the path's shape, and you don't need SMIL to animate transforms, it's quite possible to do with CSS as well.

Comment: Yep, I got that wrong. Removed the passage from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a space between scale and the (

You might want to ensure your paths are centred round the origin if you want the heart to scale from its centre rather than from the top left. Or try transform-origin but be careful not to use percentage units with transform-origin if you want it to work in Firefox.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #d9d7be;
  text-align: center;
}

.heart{
  animation: pulse linear 1s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: pulse linear 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%{transform: scale(1);}
  30%{transform: scale(1);}
  40%{transform: scale(1.08);}
  50%{transform: scale(1);}
  60%{transform: scale(1);}
  70%{transform: scale(1.05);}
  80%{transform: scale(1);}
  100%{transform: scale(1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0%{-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
  30%{-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
  40%{-webkit-transform: scale(1.08);}
  50%{-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
  60%{-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
  70%{-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);}
  80%{-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
  100%{-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="597px" height="593px" viewBox="0 0 597 593" enable-background="new 0 0 597 593" xml:space="preserve">
    <g class="heart">
   <path fill="#FF7175" d="M258.08,255.405c-0.898-7.654,0.082-16.847,6.735-20.737c8.806-5.149,19.895,3.531,23.278,13.154
  c3.316-9.961,12.405-18.064,22.851-19.111c10.447-1.047,21.467,5.766,24.211,15.9c2.152,7.952-0.72,16.59-5.632,23.206
  c-4.911,6.614-11.671,11.579-18.323,16.439c-7.933,5.795-15.865,11.59-23.795,17.384
  C281.945,295.363,259.763,269.744,258.08,255.405"/>
   <path fill="#DADCDD" d="M320.746,276.922c3.236-2.739,6.25-5.704,8.776-9.105c0.044-0.06,0.089-0.119,0.132-0.179
  c-0.043,0.06-0.088,0.119-0.132,0.179C326.996,271.218,323.982,274.183,320.746,276.922 M257.797,250.701
  c0.001-6.215,1.593-12.537,6.559-15.751C259.39,238.164,257.798,244.486,257.797,250.701 M264.814,234.668
  c0.02-0.012,0.039-0.023,0.059-0.034C264.854,234.645,264.834,234.656,264.814,234.668 M264.881,234.629
  c1.255-0.723,2.554-1.166,3.872-1.367C267.436,233.464,266.135,233.907,264.881,234.629"/>
   <path fill="#D7616B" d="M287.404,301.64c-0.006-0.006-0.011-0.012-0.016-0.019c-5.304-6.098-26.173-30.213-29.074-44.751
  c-0.1-0.5-0.178-0.989-0.234-1.465l0,0c-0.179-1.525-0.283-3.111-0.283-4.704c0.001-6.215,1.593-12.537,6.559-15.751
  c0.15-0.097,0.303-0.191,0.459-0.282l0,0c0.02-0.012,0.039-0.023,0.059-0.034c0.002-0.002,0.005-0.003,0.007-0.005
  c1.254-0.722,2.555-1.165,3.872-1.367c0.565-0.086,1.134-0.128,1.703-0.128c5.753,0,11.591,4.258,15.168,9.742
  c-1.132,9.498-7.344,20.871-3.758,28.043c0.76,1.139,1.682,1.624,2.729,1.624c5.031-0.002,12.926-11.2,19.312-14.849
  c3.27-1.961,6.828-2.855,10.305-2.855c7.234,0,14.109,3.873,17.255,10.062c-0.565,0.942-1.168,1.858-1.812,2.737
  c-0.043,0.06-0.088,0.119-0.132,0.179c-2.526,3.401-5.54,6.366-8.776,9.105c-3.059,2.587-6.315,4.973-9.547,7.334
  C303.267,290.051,295.334,295.845,287.404,301.64L287.404,301.64"/>
    </g>
  </svg>

</body> 
</html>
```